# How to use knexjs globally in a sails js application

Tags: node.js, global-variables, sails.js, waterline, knex.js

how do i get the knex object in my controllers or any other model files if i am not using waterline.

for eg.:
in my api/models/Users.js

```
module.exports = {
     find : function(id){
         // my knex query
     },
     insert : function(data){
         // my knex query again   
     } 
}
```

So in my controllers i will just do:

```
var result = Users.find(id);
```

or

```
var result = Users.insert({username : 'sailsjs'});
```

or the knex object will be available globally with out being used in the model files itself... so that i can do the knex query in the controller it self

// UsersController/index

```
index : function(req, res){
      // my knex query
}
```

Thanks
Arif

Comment: You might have to create a [custom Waterline adapter](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/custom-adapters)

Answer (score 3):

//config/bootstrap.js

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

    var Knex  = require('knex');
    var knex = Knex.initialize({
        client : "mysql",
        connection : {
            host :'localhost',
            user :'root',
            database : 'sales_force',
            password : '*******'
        }
    });
    knex.instanceId = new Date().getTime();

    sails.config.knex = knex;

  // It's very important to trigger this callack method when you are finished 
  // with the bootstrap!  (otherwise your server will never lift, since it's waiting on the bootstrap)
  cb();
};
```

// in the controller

```
var knex = sails.config.knex
```

this returns the knex object. the knex.instanceId shows that the same connection is used all over.

Please suggest if this might cause any problems.

Thanks
Arif

Comment: I would suggest creating knex.js in the config folder rather than initializing it in the bootstrap file.

Comment: @myusuf I basically disagree because it would disallow one to use clever sails config vars

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a service. `api/services`

Answer (score 0):

Best Option to use Knex Js globally in Sails Js (Tested for Version 1+) is to create a file named knex.js inside config directory, like this:

```js
/**
 * Knex Js, Alternate DB Adapter, In case needed, it is handy for doing migrations
 * (sails.config.knex)
 *
 *
 * For all available options, see:
 * http://knexjs.org/
 */

const developmentDBConfig = require('./datastores');
const stagingDBConfig = require('./env/staging');
const productionDBConfig = require('./env/production');


function getConnectionString() {
  let dbConnectionString = developmentDBConfig.datastores.default.url;

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
    dbConnectionString = stagingDBConfig.datastores.default.url;
  }

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    dbConnectionString = productionDBConfig.datastores.default.url;
  }

  return dbConnectionString;
}


module.exports.knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'postgresql',
  connection: getConnectionString()
});
```

Now, in any file(helpers/controllers/views etc..) you can set and use knex as:

```js
// Now use this knex object for anything like:
let user = await sails.config.knex('user').select('*').first();
```